# Wrong posts sequence at home page [Django app]

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

At my home-page I've got exhibited all posts on my blog, but they're sorted incorrectly, from the oldest post to newest(it has to be reversed).
I use querysets to sort posts order by published date in my views.py

```
def home(request):
   posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
   return render(request, "home.html", {'posts': posts})
```

And that's my home.html source code:

```html
{% extends "C:\myapp\blog\templates\base.html" %}
{% block content %}
 {% for post in posts %}
  <div class="post">
   <div class="date">
    {{ post.published_date }}
   </div>
   <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
   
   <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
  </div>
 {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Could you help me in reverse these posts?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a `-` to the string argument in [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) this will cause your queryset to be in descending order.

```
def home(request):
   posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
   return render(request, "home.html", {'posts': posts})
```

Notice the `.order_by('-published_date')`

Comment: @dannyxn if this answer has helped you consider helping me by accepting it as an answer. You can do so by clicking the check to the left of the answer.

Comment: Done, I've one more question, how can I ask you about it?